# No wifi autoconnect

Tags: networking, network-manager, lenovo, vpn

I've got a Lenove Yoga 720 which works quite nice out of the box with Ubuntu 18.04, however after setting up VPN I'm unable to autoconnect to wifi when I start or when resuming from suspend. Rather annoying since Gnome requires five mouse clicks altogether to open the network dialog, selecting network and connecting. Plus, I have to manually reload open tabs. Once connected to wifi, VPN auto connects nicely. I've not been able to resolve this issue based on advice from related threads on Ask Ubuntu.

```
user@pc$ifconfig
<snip>
wlp63s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.151  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::5715:5c3:8e58:58f3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 3c:95:09:63:8c:21  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 623886  bytes 792613698 (792.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 205568  bytes 62069644 (62.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

sudo lshw -class network
[sudo] password: passwd
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3f:00.0
       logical name: wlp63s0
       version: 32
       serial: 3c:95:09:63:8c:21
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.15.0-31-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=192.168.1.151 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:132 memory:75000000-751fffff
```

Comment: is "connectivity checking" turned on under **Settings** -> **Privacy**

Comment: Yes, "connectivity checking" is turned On.